# Log Errors in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, logging, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to figure out how to log from my Mobile Service with a .NET backend. So far, I've read that you can do this by calling:

```
ApiController.ApiServices.Log.Info("log string")
```

This is fine if you're in an ApiController as you can simply use `this.Services`, but what would you do if you wanted to log from somewhere besides a controller? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If by "besides a controller" you mean in a custom controller, you can declare

```
public ApiServices Services { get; set; }
```

and then use the `Services.Log.Error("your error")`

If this is not what you're asking, please give some more information.